# Ionic 2 app not working in android 4.2.2

Tags: android, button, ionic2

Hi i am still new to ionic 2 and android ,my app is totally working fine in browser and device higher than 4.4.2
But in 4.2.2 menu button doesn't trigger and navigation not happening.how can i make my app to work fine in android 4.2.2  ,
i'll add my manifest file below

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="0.0.1" package="com.ionicframework.myionic2project169652" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@mipmap/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <provider android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true" android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
        </provider>
    </application>
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="14" />
    <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="17" />
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ionic 2 supports Android 4.4 and up, if you need to support older versions you could use [crosswalk](https://crosswalk-project.org/)

Comment: thanks amin i searched what is the minimum supported android version but answer is found nowhere